# how to put schedule task jobs in chain in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am using laravel task scheduling inside it queue jobs or working i want to put these jobs in chain 
`kernel.php`

```
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment)->dailyAt('16:15')->timezone('Australia/Melbourne');
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\UploadFileFTP)->dailyAt('16:15')->timezone('Australia/Melbourne');
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment)->dailyAt('16:15')->timezone('Australia/Melbourne');           
    $schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment)->dailyAt('16:15')->timezone('Australia/Melbourne');
```

I tried to use laravel withChain method but its not working .

I want to run these job in chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `call` closure, to add a new callback to the `$schedule` and then within use `withChain` to dispatch chained jobs, starting with first one:

```
 $schedule->call(function(){
           \App\Jobs\FetchEmailAttachment::withChain([
                new \App\Jobs\UploadFileFTP,
                new \App\Jobs\SplitAttachment,
                new \App\Jobs\ResendAttachment,             
            ])->dispatch();
 })
 ->dailyAt('16:15')
 ->timezone('Australia/Melbourne');
```